# Getting extra garbage with AES 256 decrypt (php, phpseclilb, openssl)

Tags: php, openssl, aes, phpseclib, cbc-mode

I have the following PHP code:

```
require('/var/www/third_party_plugins/phpseclib/vendor/autoload.php');
use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;
use phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib3\Math\BigInteger;
use phpseclib3\Crypt\AES;
use phpseclib3\Crypt\Random;
$message = hex2bin('f5f905e8b2d8f0a72e179a169a59bc373021a75865e55c6797627bc43ddc6af0d9bd673bf94f5e8defc5af81019fd87c7d504a6aa758ba1e2f1f9858d0293b0b');
$key = hex2bin('d2ce45fd5f80c15db0a4ab26a7e27f42b507ed9469f0d63c1dbe4f89ed84c0c2');
$iv = hex2bin('db9d7e844b00282327221bb563639f96');
$cipher = new AES('cbc');
$cipher->setIV($iv);
$cipher->setKey($key);
//$cipher->disablePadding();
$Decrypted = bin2hex($cipher->decrypt($message));
print("\n" . $Decrypted . "\n");
```

When I run this code, I get the following result:

```
240dcbefc0f82fadc00ef8494488aaa81400000c2def01e79fec6c4d9a822358dd8a910cac606e8afcb607793cb442093a56b7b40b
```

Inside of this result, I can see the message I WANT, which is:

```
1400000c2def01e79fec6c4d9a822358
```

However, there are 16 bytes of data in the front of the message which make no sense to me, it seems like some kind of padding, but I dont want it in my result nor do I understand why it is there, because from what I understand the padding should be removed by phpseclib or openssl functions

```
240dcbef c0f82fad c00ef849 4488aaa8
```

I understand that there is a 20 byte MAC at the end, however, I notice ONE extra byte in front of the mac:

```
dd8a910cac606e8afcb607793cb442093a56b7b40b  // THIS IS 21 BYTES, NOT 20...why?
```

I'm also having trouble re-encrypting the data and getting a valid response from the server, as I'm re-encrypting it with PHP, then sending the SAME data to my C# server, and it is unable to decrypt the message.

Comment: The document is not good, however, as usual, IV is prepended and tags are appended. It should be your IV. Chech with [getIV](https://api.phpseclib.com/3.0/phpseclib3/Crypt/AES.html#method_getIV)?

Comment: Well the plaintext is _part_ of the decrypted text. As for what the rest means...  you'd need to give us more context to be able to give you any meaningful advice. Like you say "_I understand that there is a 20 byte MAC at the end_". That's absolutely not something we say definitely on our own. Likewise no one can say definitely what the first 32 bytes mean without more context. Like where is this encrypted string coming from? What does the documentation for where-ever this string came from look like?

Comment: BUT if all you want to do is get the plaintext and nothing else then `bin2hex(substr($cipher->decrypt($message), 16, -21));` should probably do the trick.

Comment: "_I'm also having trouble re-encrypting the data and getting a valid response from the server_". Again, we'd need _context_. Can you share us with some sort of documentation? I mean, if it's expecting a MAC address then what algorithm is the MAC address using? Whatever algorithm it's using is 20 bytes long I guess. The only hash algorithm I'm aware that uses a length like that is sha1. But that's not something we should need to be guessing at - it should be clearly documented somewhere.

Comment: "_from what I understand the padding should be removed by phpseclib or openssl functions_". when phpseclib and openssl remove padding they do so from the end of the string. And the padding needs to be PKCS8 padding. eg. take a look at the last byte and remove that many bytes from the end. So if the ciphertext is one character shy of being a multiple of the block length the padding would be `"\x01"` and thus `"\x01"` would be removed. If you're having "padding" added at the beginning it is most likely something else.